# Are there special values Windows never uses for a processID?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, api, vb6

During a code review I found the original programmer making the assumption his program will never get the 1010 (one thousand and ten) PID.

So there is an hard coded test on PID 1010.

- Is it safe code?
- Is it a value windows never uses?

Thank you.

Comment: @jeffamaphone good question but we all know the answer to that

Comment: Well, I couldn't find it, but the ntdef.h header cited below is pretty strong documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No program can obtain a `1010` (one thousand and ten) PID. All PID (and all kernel handles) will be multipes of four as the two lower bits of its value will be 0

Extracted from `ntdef.h`

```
//
// Low order two bits of a handle are ignored by the system and available
// for use by application code as tag bits.  The remaining bits are opaque
// and used to store a serial number and table index.
//
```

Comment: A process ID isn't a handle, is it?

Comment: Task manager shows they are all multiples of 4. So code is safe. Anyway, using null or some other clear default value would make more readable code. - Thank you.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, no, they are not handles, but to obtain the pid, the os uses the same subroutine (`ExCreateHandle`) that is used for handle creation. More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/02/28/7925962.aspx), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/21/358109.aspx), [here](http://i-web.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/edu/training/ss/lecture/new-documents/Lectures/13-Processes/Processes.pdf)